# Snappy codec in Hadoop and x86

Tags: hadoop

I got the following WARNs from ARM server:

```
13/06/10 01:31:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/06/10 01:31:06 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
```

But I don't get these WANRs in x86 server. Is Snappy code coming with Hadoop package but only supporting x86?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/snappy/source/browse/trunk/README, I see snappy codec is optimized for x86 so I am guessing it is not loaded in non x86 server in Hadoop?